# Are C++ versions of C standard library functions in the std:: namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

"C++ Primer" (5th edition) states on page `91` the advantage of including the `C++` version of a `C` standard library header instead of the `.h` version: this way the included names end up in the `std::` namespace and do not pollute the global namespace.

I tried including `cstdio` and was surprised to observe that I can use `printf()` without specifying `std::`. Interestingly, including only `iostream` or only `string` is also sufficient to get access to a global `printf()`. Am I missing something?

I am compiling with `g++ 4.8.2` with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11`.

Comment: So, is there any advantage left for `<cfoo>` over `<foo.h>`?

Comment: yes - you should use functions prefixed by std::, just to make your code more clean and explicit :) Also - hopefully at some point standard will forbid global namespace pollution

Comment: I missed the other post and it does answer the question. Should I delete my post or leave it?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg With some luck the next guy who misses the other post will find yours. That's why duplicates are linked and not deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

It is *unspecified* whether `<cfoo>` also puts the names into the global namespace. All C library names are reserved in the global namespace in C++.

[extern.names]/3:

> Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in namespace std and in the global namespace.

To restate this:

- in order to use a name in `std`, *you must* include the correct header.
- You *must not* redefine any names from the C standard library in the above contexts.
- Nothing says whether any particular names from the C standard library are declared (unless you explicitly include the deprecated header `<foo.h>`).