# What is the benefit of using ::namespace::something over namespace::something?

Tags: c++, namespaces

The code at my new workplace accesses namespaces using a seemingly redundant scope resolution at the start. For example, `::std::vector<int>` instead of `std::vector<int>`.<sup>[1]</sup> I have never seen namespace access being done this way before.

One somewhat contrived scenario I could think of is when some namespace `ns` declares a nested namespace `std`, which too has a `vector` (in this example). Then the "additional" `::` at the left ensures that the global `std::vector` is being used, not the local one. However, this is unlikely to be the reason given that our code goes through a rather elaborate review process making it almost impossible for anyone to introduce a new `std` namespace.

Are there any other scenarios where this could make a difference?

---

<sup>[1] I asked a few senior developers in the team to explain this to me, but they only have a vague idea why this "convention" is being used. The earliest developers who wrote the code left the team years ago, and nobody asked them about it before they left.</sup>

Comment: I think you answer your question, I don't see any other reason of doing that

Comment: @Garf365 Yes, that was one scenario I could think of, just wanted to check if the experts here know of anything else. Sometimes such questions lead to learning something entirely unexpected. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most notable scenario I can imagine is when using `std::tolower` and iterating over a container:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

std::string str = "Masked Man";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543264/3494013) answer by @MatthieuM., it is a name clash between the `tolower` functions from `<locale>` and `<cctype>`. Since, on your implementation ([it's actually unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136022/are-c-versions-of-c-standard-library-functions-in-the-std-namespace)), the C standard library functions perpetuated in the C++ standard library are in the `std` **and** the global namespace, `::tolower` explicitly uses the one from `<cctype>`.

So, **explicitly accessing the C standard library part of the C++ standard library** counts as another reason, IMO.

Comment: It's correct now, but I would indeed use `<ctype.h>`  if I had to disambiguate between `std::tolower` and `::tolower` (even though the use of .h C standard headers is deprecated).

Comment: This doesn't explain why anyone would use a `::` prefix in `::std::tolower`.